# I have figured out most of this assignment and I have added a second part that contains radio buttons.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to use two radio buttons one for a new customer and the other for an existing customer. The existing customer radio button will take the selected line in my list box and put the information in three textboxes. Am I supposed to use a split to get the information from the list box to the textboxes. I input the data for the first part of the homework and when I click new customer radiobox it will add the information to my new list box but I am having trouble with the radio buttons they are at the bottom of my code. I have commented my code up to this part so i hope that it is understandable how I have been doing everything.

```
Private Sub btnProcess_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
    'I am dimming my variables that I need 
    Dim name As String
    Dim address As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim firstlast As String
    Dim invoicenumber As String
    Dim chairs As Double
    Dim sofas As Double

    'I am assigning value to my variables
    name = txtName.Text
    address = txtAddress.Text
    city = txtCity.Text
    chairs = CDbl(txtChairs.Text) * 350
    sofas = CDbl(txtSofas.Text) * 925

    'I am using if clauses to make sure the user puts values into the text boxes and if not then a message box will appear
    If name = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Name.")
        txtName.Focus()
    End If
    If address = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Address.")
        txtAddress.Focus()
    End If
    If city = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your City, State, and Zip in Correct Format.")
        txtCity.Focus()
    End If
    If address.Contains(",") = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter In Correct Format:  City, St., Zip.")
    End If

    'These are my functions that I made for the invoice number and name reverse
    invoicenumber = GenerateinvoiceNumber(txtName.Text)
    firstlast = RevName(name)

    'I am adding all of the items to my listbox
    lstResults.Items.Clear()
    lstResults.Items.Add("INVOICE NUMBER: " & " " & invoicenumber.ToUpper)
    lstResults.Items.Add(String.Empty)
    lstResults.Items.Add("Name: " & "   " & RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper))
    lstResults.Items.Add("Address: " & "" & address.ToUpper)
    lstResults.Items.Add("City: " & "       " & city.ToUpper)
    lstResults.Items.Add(String.Empty)
    lstResults.Items.Add("Number of Chairs: " & "" & txtChairs.Text)
    lstResults.Items.Add("Number of Sofas: " & " " & txtSofas.Text)
    lstResults.Items.Add(String.Empty)
    lstResults.Items.Add("Cost: " & "           " & FormatCurrency(chairs + sofas))
    lstResults.Items.Add("Sales Tax:" & "   " & FormatCurrency((chairs + sofas) * 0.05))
    lstResults.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------")
    lstResults.Items.Add("Total Cost: " & " " & FormatCurrency((chairs + sofas) * 1.05))

End Sub
'This is the function for the name reverse. 
Function RevName(ByVal name As String) As String

    Dim firstlast() As String

    'This split is to take the part of the word after the comma
    firstlast = Split(txtName.Text.ToUpper, ", ")
    'This if clause is to make sure that the name is formatted correctly with a comma
    If name.Contains(", ") = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Name In Correct Format.")
    End If

    'This will show the function and the correct formatting in my list box
    Return firstlast(1) & " " & firstlast(0)

End Function
'This is my function to create the invoice number
Function GenerateinvoiceNumber(ByVal s As String) As String
    'Dimming the variables I need for my function
    Dim initials() As String
    Dim firstInitial, invoicenumber, city As String

    'Assigning values to the variables
    'I am using a split to get the letters from the last name
    initials = s.Split(CChar(","))
    'I am taking the letters that I need using a substring
    firstInitial = initials(0).Trim.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper

    city = txtCity.Text
    'This is to get the value of the textbox city and the length of the input
    Dim length = city.Length
    'This is to get the first two letters of the name behind the comma and the city substring will extract the last four characters in the city textbox
    invoicenumber = (firstInitial & city.Substring(length - 4, 4))
    'This is to return the value of the function
    Return invoicenumber
End Function
Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'This is to clear the form and start over
    txtName.Clear()
    txtAddress.Clear()
    txtCity.Clear()
    txtChairs.Clear()
    txtSofas.Clear()
    lstResults.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'This is to end the entire form
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnNew_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnNew.CheckedChanged
    lstCustomer.Items.Add(RevName(txtName.Text.ToUpper) & (txtAddress.Text) & (txtCity.Text))
End Sub


Private Sub rbtnExisting_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnExisting.CheckedChanged
    Dim name1 As String
    Dim address2 As String
    Dim city2 As String

    name1 = txtName.Text
    address2 = txtAddress.Text
    city2 = txtCity.Text

    lstCustomer.GetSelected(CInt(ToTextBoxes(Name, address2, city2)))

End Sub
Function ToTextBoxes(ByRef name As String, ByRef Address As String, ByRef city As String) As String
    Dim output() As String
    output = Split(lstCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString(), ",")


    Return CStr(CStr(output(0) = txtName.Text) & output(1) = txtAddress.Text & output(2) = CBool(txtCity.Text))

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: whats the problem now?

Comment: I have to use two radio buttons the second radio button is supposed to take the information selected in a listbox and break it up and display it into three textboxes. one text box for name, one for address, and one for city. I keep getting an error code and I do not understand what I need to do to get the information into the textboxes.

Comment: @AntwinetteJones - What **exactly** is the exception error message ? Don't just explain what's happening in words, **write** the exact error details paragraph issued by the debugger. If by _error code_ you meant _code typos_ (in source code highlighted by the IDE) what is the error message ? You won't get anywhere near putting text in the 3 texboxes without identifying what was the cause of the error. Start by giving details on the issue, don't focus on the goal.

Comment: NullReference exception was not handled.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    It is with this line of code:    Function ToTextBoxes(ByRef name As String, ByRef Address As String, ByRef city As String) As String
        Dim output() As String
        output = Split(lstCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString(), ",")


        Return CStr(CStr(output(0) = txtName.Text) & output(1) = txtAddress.Text & output(2) = CBool(txtCity.Text))

    End Function

Comment: NREs are all the same - you are using something which is Nothing.  When it happens, hover the mouse over different things to see which one it is.  in this case, I suspect it is `lstCustomer.SelectedItem` is the user hasnt selected anything, it will be Nothing.

Comment: I had information put in the text box and the information goes to my listbox and when I select the line in the list box the textboxes are supposed to display in the text boxes again but it throws this exception and the output is not going to the text boxes I do not understand how to add the information from the list that is selected to split up to the three text boxes